# Renaming columns in a loop R

Tags: r, loops

I have tried searching how to rename columns of multiple data frames in a loop, but I can't find a cohesive answer. Let's say I have 4 data frames that have 2 columns each. I want to rename each y1 column as "number" and each y2 column as "value" in all 4 data frames. I know that I can do this by creating a list, but I want to change the name of the column directly for that data frame, not as a data frame list value (like df_list[[1]]). I get that type of result when I use this code:

```
df_list <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4)

for (i in 1:length(df_list)){
  colnames(df_list[[i]]) <- c("number", "value")
}
```

Data frames:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1), y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
d4 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1), y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
```

Comment: *but I can't find a cohesive answer* ... possibly because this can be done many ways in R. Your question is not clear. Does code not work?

Comment: Also, you should be saving similar structured objects in a list (preferably a named list) in the first place instead of many similar objects flooding global environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest would be `setNames`

```
lapply(df_list, setNames, c("number", "value"))
```

---

As @Parfait mentioned, it is better to have objects in a `list` rather than changing the objects in the global environment, but it can be done if the `list` name is also the object name

```
list2env(lapply(mget(paste0("d", 1:4)), setNames, 
         c("number", "value")), envir = .GlobalEnv)
names(d1)
#[1] "number" "value"
```

Or using a `for` loop

```
for(nm in paste0("d", 1:4)) assign(nm, `names<-`(get(nm), c("number", "value")))
```

Comment: This, however, changes the column names of the data frames within df_list, so that if I type df_list[[1]], I see the correct data frames. However, my original d1 remains unchanged. Is there a way to directly rename the columns of the data frames?

Comment: @user10156381  Can you please check the updated code?